# Make SVG Circle stroke-dashoffset animate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg-animate

I would like to animate the SVG Circle's strokeDashoffset,

I make a circle,
I get data from an array (will be a database later on)
which changes the strokeDashoffset
at the moment it doesn't animate smoothly, I'd like a ease-in-out 1s
if I wanted it to go from 0 to a 100% I'd use keyframes with "from{}" and "to{}" in css, 
but I would like to animate any changes happening, cause there will be some color changing as well.

```
<svg>
      <circle
        cx="50%"
        cy="50%"
        r={radiusHR}
        fill="none"
        stroke={strokedefaultcolor}
        strokeWidth={strokewidth}
      />
      <circle
        id="HRprogress"
        cx="50%"
        cy="50%"
        r={radiusHR}
        fill="none"
        stroke="#E1E5FA"
        strokeWidth={strokewidth}
        strokeDasharray={circumferenceHR}
        strokeDashoffset={circumferenceHR * (1 - this.props.value1 / 101)}
      />

</svg>
```

Comment: could you create a [runnable example using stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the props in `style` attribute, and set a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition). For example:

```
const Circle = (props) => (
  <circle
    cx="50%"
    cy="50%"
    r={radius}
    fill="none"
    style={{
      stroke: props.color,
      transition: 'all 0.3s',
      strokeWidth: props.width,
      strokeDasharray: props.dashArray,
      strokeDashoffset: props.dashOffset
    }}
  />
);
```

Full example with random values every 800 ms:

```js
const Circle = ({ // default values used if not given in props
  radius,
  color = 'lightslategray',
  width = 1,
  dashArray = '0',
  dashOffset = 0
}) => (
  <circle
    cx="50%"
    cy="50%"
    r={radius}
    fill="none"
    style={{
      stroke: color,
      transition: 'all 0.3s ease-in-out', // animation duration and easing function
      strokeWidth: width,
      strokeDasharray: dashArray,
      strokeDashoffset: dashOffset
    }}
  />
);

class Circles extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { // initial values
      dashOffset: 0,
      dashArray: '10, 10',
      width: 1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval( // change to some random crap every 800 ms
      () =>
        this.setState({
          dashOffset: this.state.dashOffset + 10,
          dashArray: `${Math.random() * 10}, 10`,
          width: 1 + Math.random() * 4
        }),
      800
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg>
        <Circle
          radius={50}
          color="#eb26a8"
          width={this.state.width}
          dashArray={this.state.dashArray}
          dashOffset={this.state.dashOffset * 1}
        />
        <Circle
          radius={60}
          color="#2645eb"
          width={this.state.width * 2}
          dashArray={this.state.dashArray}
          dashOffset={this.state.dashOffset * 4}
        />
        <Circle
          radius={70}
          width={2}
          dashArray="1, 5"
        />
        <Circle
          radius={25}
          width={2}
          dashArray="1, 5"
        />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Circles />,
  document.getElementById("mount")
);
```

```html
<div id="mount"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

List of timing functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function

You can even create a custom one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick, I tried this before but it wouldn't work for some reason, I think I was missing the xtra { } within the {}!

Comment: Yeah, these nested braces are a bit tricky. Think of it as `let someObject = { color: '…' }` and `<Circle style={ someObject } />`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [Greensock Animation Platform](https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/DrawSVGPlugin) for this sort of thing. Here's how I did it in Firmament Wars, a browser RTS game that I made:

```
TweenMax.to([DOM.targetLine, DOM.targetLineShadow], .2, {
    startAt: {
        strokeDashoffset: 0
    },
    strokeDashoffset: -12,
    repeat: -1,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});
```

It comes with any ease you can think of, so they take care of that, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would't be so easy, as React uses a virtual DOM… Also maybe a bit of a overkill for just animating few SVG properties. But yeah, seems to be possible: https://medium.com/@marcmintel/react-meets-gsap-c6dd82edeb72